# PHP mysql_insert_id() for MySQL UUID() primary keys?

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key, uuid, mysql-insert-id

Is there some equivalent to PHP `mysql_insert_id` to fetch the last inserted UUID() primary key? (I always get 0. It works for auto_inc integers though)

Comment: unfortunately I don't think there is. Also, please discontinue using mysql_* functions and use either mysqli_* functions or PDO objects instead.

Comment: well, other than break support for legacy php installs... is there something in PDO for this?

Comment: how "legacy" are we talking? [Mysqli](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) is pretty well supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, last_insert_id() only retrieves that last generated auto_increment fields. You'll have to do a `select uuid()` first, then do an insert using that uuid.

However, note that uuids can't be guaranteed to be unique - they're simply very unlikely to collide. If you do require uniqueness, then go with an auto_increment - they'll never be re-used within any single table.

Comment: I had thought auto_increment fails when you shard to different servers, hence the usage of UUID's?

Comment: @ina yes, sharding (whether or not it is to different servers) can cause auto_increment failure, if you switch partitions. But, when you partition ("shard") a table your PK effectively becomes the auto_increment value plus whatever column you're partitioning on.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand why many systems use UUID for a user's primary id. I had thought it was because they assumed the database would scale across different servers, and the mac-address in the UUID helps determine which server the data is on. But, if an id is guaranteed to be unique and can scale, why use UUID's.

Answer (score 1):

I found this quite short and simple solution:

```
set @id=UUID();
insert into <table>(<col1>,<col2>) values (@id,'another value');
select @id;
```